# Module for requiring some authors' texts to be approved by admin

Tags: 7

I am developing a site for a client that wishes to have two levels of content administrators, editor and admin. The editor is supposed to be able to edit their own content but an admin has to approve it before it is published. All content is versioned on the site so one version would be displayed to the site visitor while a newer version is in review mode. Once it is approved by an admin it can be published.

Is there any module available for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module. You will need to dig deeper to have a revision show up while the next one is being moderated, but I'm sure it can be done with [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Comment: Worked like a charm. It did exactly what I wanted without me having to do any modifications :)